# Can we use python related api's on the Django templates?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django and hence not having thorough knowledge about it. So I am facing a few errors in Django.

Currently I am trying to print the type of a variable from the Django template html file as follows:

```
<center><h2>The type of feature list report for version {%type(version)%} is<h2></center>
```

For the above, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'type(version)'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

So what's going wrong here? How can we use the python related api's (like type(), strip(), get(), etc) from the html template files? I think inside the {% .... %} we can use python related evaluations. Am I right?

Please throw some lights on this .

Comment: First of all you have to pass the values to the django template you are working on like as a context data. Then only you can get the value.  You can't do more operation over here. Django template is only for view or rendering so, just pass it and show it don't do more operations here. It will be good practice to doing so.

Comment: I have already passed the values to the django template. So after passing the value, we can't do any more operation on that?

Comment: Either switch to jinja2 and declare type as a safe function or don't try to program in templates (this is the philosophy of the Django Template Language).

Comment: It is not a good approach @RDX In general, just make sure your view passes your template the right data and you shouldn't have to do much work to make sure it comes out in html, just example  if you want to try length of value in python you can use len(your_data) but here a small  change is to get length of  a string like {{obj.data1 | length}}. here braces for len() will not work. Choose wisely. My recommendation is to do it from your views.

Answer (score 1):

As said, this is not the philosophy of DTL, but some functions that transform input are implemented as [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/dev/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference).

In addition, you can write your own filters and supporting a "type" filter, would be very simple:

```py
from django import template
from typing import Any

register = template.Library()

def filter_type(value: Any) -> str:
    return str(type(value))

register.filter('type', filter_type)
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for details.

Both Jinja's and DTL's approach are explicit over implicit: instead of blindly supporting any python function with all it's dangers, you have to explicitly allow it or implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Running arbitrary Python code in a Django template is intentionally disabled. Aside from security concerns, the reason is your project's business logic should be separate from your presentation layer. This is part of good application design.

There are three primary ways you can call an operation from a Django template.

1. Pass in a function and call it.
2. Use a template filter, either custom or built in.
3. Use a template tag, either custom or built in.

#### Pass in a function and call it.

Calling a passed in function from a Django template is standard. However, it has two caveats.

1. The function must return a value that can is a string or can be coerced to a string. (Otherwise nothing will be printed in the template.)
2. The function must not have any required arguments.

The most common use case is either a computed value or a getter e.g.

```py
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
```

```html
<h1>{{ page.get_title }}</h1>
```

#### Template filters

See [Melvyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044092/10463261) for an example of template filters.

Template filters operate on a value. So this is perfect for a Python function like `type()`.

#### Template Tags

**Edited: see Melvyn's comment.**

Simple Template tags on the other hand work more like a function. They accept positional and keyword arguments and should again return a value. I won't go into inclusion tags or advanced tag compilation and rendering here, but you can read about it in the [Django custom template tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Here is an example of two template tags I often include in a project in `debug.py`.

```py
import pprint
from django import template

register = template.Library()
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=120)


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def print_context(context):
    pp.pprint(context)
    return ""


@register.simple_tag()
def print_thing(thing):
    pp.pprint(thing)
    return ""
```

I can use `print_context` to print the current context in terminal and `print_thing` to print something.

```html
{% load debug %}
{% print_context %}

{% print_thing 'print this string' %}
```

You can create a template tag that will do anything a standard Python function can do. This is because a template tag essentially calls the function you create.

Use the constraints of the Django template system to your advantage to create well designed applications where the business logic is located in the views, models, and helpers, and not in the templates.

Comment: Nice write up. However: template tags do not *have* to return a value. Classic example being the {% for %} tag. I won't go into the difference between functions and routines, cause I don't think anyone knows that any more. :)

Comment: Thank you! That is a good point. I was primarily thinking of simple tags which will render `None` if no value is returned. But you are right, both inclusion tags and more complex tags operate very differently.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a class which includes the type, so you can call the type like: `variable.type` or you can send the type data from the controller. 
If you need to make reactive programming logic at the front end, I'd suggest you use Vue, React or Angular.